# Can anyone provide historical datasets giving country-by-country ratio of export-agriculture sector to domestic-use-agriculture sector?

Tags: economy, data-sources, agriculture, imperialism

Essentially, I want to examine the effect of agricultural commercialization on a number of factors and considered this a good place to start. Does anyone know of any such datasets, preferably extending back to the colonial period?

Moreover, are there any better ways to operationalize the extent or rate of agricultural commercialization?

Comment: I think this question would be good for History SE!